# How can I create a custom styled EntryElement with MonoTouch.dialog?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, styles, subclass, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to create a custom entry element using monotouch.dialog. I understand how to subclass a StringElement to style my own string elements - see example below:

```
public class CustomStyledStringElementPlain : MonoTouch.Dialog.StyledStringElement
{
    public CustomStyledStringElementPlain (string _caption, UIColor _backgroundcolour, UITextAlignment _alignment) : base(string.Empty,string.Empty)
    {
        TextColor = UIColor.White;
        Font = UIFont.FromName ("Helvetica-Bold", 14f);
        Caption = _caption;
        Alignment = _alignment;
        BackgroundColor = _backgroundcolour;
    }
}
```

However, when subclassing EntryElement, I am not able to access properties for the BackgroundColor for example (which is the main thing I want to change!) Here is what I have so far... Any pointers or advice on how I could change the background color or otherwise style entry elements would be much appreciated!

```
public class CustomStyledEntryElementPlain : MonoTouch.Dialog.EntryElement
{
    public CustomStyledEntryElementPlain (string _caption, UIColor _colour, UITextAlignment _alignment) : base(string.Empty,string.Empty)
    {
        ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
        Caption = _caption;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize a MonoTouch.Dialog Element, you can override the GetCell method and set the appearance you want on the cell object. Something like this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView) {
    var cell = base.GetCell(tableView);
    cell.BackgroundColor = _colour;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you NilsH, nice and easy! I have had a good look through the properties now and am able to change all the text and background colours. I couldn't see anything to change the cell border colour or width. Do these properties not exist? Would I be better off using a UIImage for the cell background to get what I want?

Comment: If you want full freedom, you can replace any View in the UITableViewCell you want. Check the [API docs for UITableViewCell](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewCell%2fP)

Comment: *Edit - I see that I can access the cell's .Layer property and then adjust items there... I am able to draw a rectangle around my cell, but the old rounded white rectangle is left behind... Any ideas as to how I remove it? Screenshot to illustrate: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1230453/example.png - the red border is what I made using layer properties, but the white border is what still remains behind - any idea how to change that colour, or alternatively, remove it so I can instead use the red border?