# Disable button in MT.Dialog and change image

Tags: ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

Can anyone help, i want to change my image(button), when i press my buttonImage i open MT.Dialog and then i login, and when i login i want the button to change how do i do that, i have found the code, but it doesn't work in MT.Dialog
Here is how i do it.

```
    cmdLogin.TouchUpInside += delegate { 
      cmdLogin.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Images/Logout.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
    };
```

and for the hidden thing i tried(But doesn't work)

```
    if(cmdLogin.Hidden == True)
    {
       cmdLogout.Enabled;
    }else{
       cmdLogout.Hidden;
    }
```

but that doesn't work in MT.Dialog ofcourse because i don't do anything with my string element(My string element got the name **login** and if someone got a link to a good login system w/ database that would be very helpful.

and ofcourse here is my MT.Dialog code

```
    cmdLogin.TouchUpInside += delegate {

            _window.RootViewController = new DialogViewController(new RootElement("Login") {

                    new Section ("B.V. Electronic"){
                    (password = new EntryElement ("Password", "", "", true))
                },
                new Section () {
                    (login = new StringElement ("Login", delegate {
                        if(password.Matches("1234")){

                            GoBackToView();

                        }else{
                            new UIAlertView("Wrong code", "It's the wrong code", null, "Ok", null).Show();

                        }
                    }))
                },
                new Section (){
                    new StringElement ("Cancel", delegate {
                        GoBackToView();
                })
                }


            });
        };
```

Comment: And can someone tell me how i do this. I got a button, when i press the button i want to refer(sorry for spelling mistakes)to another project/solution so it opens that project up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not real clear on exactly what you want to do. However, one suggestion I have for you is to look at this:

https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/tree/master/FieldService

This is a sample application that was built by Xamarin that has a nice login screen that you could try and get some ideas from. It does not use Monotouch.Dialog for the login screen, so if you want that you can look at this:

http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/create_a_login_window_using_monotouch.dialog

Your code is similar to that, but it looks like you modified it a little.

If you want to change your Login StringElement, you need to modify it, then call `Root.Reload(login, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);` afterwards. I don't think there is a simple way to just change the background image of a StringElement. You will need to make your own subclass of StringElement and customize the `GetCell()` routine to. You can refer to this SO question for more ideas on that:

[How can I create a custom styled EntryElement with MonoTouch.dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666960/how-can-i-create-a-custom-styled-entryelement-with-monotouch-dialog)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my login screen is a bit different, because I want to make sure you have entered the correct password, I don't know any other way to check password credentials. Also I don't want to change my StringElement, I got a login button, and when I press the login button(looks like an image), I open a MT.D, and when I press login, I go back to the view with my login button, and it needs to be changed to a logout button(with image). I already got the button in the view all it needs is to be visible when I Login, and the login button needs to be hidden. I hope it make sense.

Comment: And also, that is Android, and I need Ios, xamarin says it can't open the solution because it's android and not Ios :/

Comment: The FieldService project is not just android, it has both projects in the solution. The solution has nothing to do with a platform, only the projects do. It might not be able to open the Android project, which is ok because you dont need it. You can just delete that from your solution if you want.

Comment: Can you tell how to get a NavigationsController inside my MT.Dialog, so i can go back, instead of a StringElement

Comment: You put a DialogViewController inside a UINavigationController, not the other way around. If you have more questions about that, post on the Xamarin forums where I have lots of code examples to help.